# Galen: Text verification

Tags: selenium, galen

I have just started using Galen with Java + TestNG framework and am trying to figure out how to verify text of an element that has a CSS property `display: none` associated with it.

Dom structure of that element looks something like this

```
<td id="invoice-gridrow-1-cell-2">
    <span class="textbox-container horizontal-layout controlElement">
        <input class="textbox-control cost right" type="text" value="1" id="invoice-gridrow-1-cell-2-txt-0" aria-label="">
        <span class="shadow-textbox textbox-control cost right" tabindex="0">1</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Element `span class="shadow-textbox textbox-control cost right"`has a property `display: none` associated with itself.

I would like to verify the text of that span (`span class="shadow-textbox textbox-control cost right"`), but it says that the element **is not visible on page**

I tried to verify text of its parent span element `span class="textbox-container horizontal-layout controlElement"`, but it says that **`the text is "" but should be "1"`**

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any attribute as `display: none` within the element `<span class="shadow-textbox textbox-control cost right" tabindex="0">1</span>`. Can you update the question with the exact _HTML_ please?

Comment: @DebanjanB There is a CSS file that has that property, it is not explicitly specified using the ``style`` tag.

Comment: Which `CSS file`? Any reason to conclude that the `CSS file` is applied on this element?

Comment: Yes, the element is actually not visible on the page. Also, ``false`` is returned on executing the following selenium command ``weblement.isDisplayed()``.

Comment: First you need to get under the real issue if the element is returning **false** through `weblement.isDisplayed()` naturally or else the element is having `style` attribute **display: none**. These are two distinct cases and the solutions are diverse.

Comment: Let's just assume that the element is not visible on the page (to the human eye).